# Python redis library not working unlike command line

Tags: python, redis

I have a remote Linux Redis 7.0 server which I reach through a spiped tunnel.

Launch spiped locally:

```
spiped -F -e -s 127.0.0.1:6379 -t REMOTESERVER:6379 -k /etc/spiped/redis.key
```

and as expected I can connect to the remote Redis server via the command line utility:

```
(redis_test) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini redis_test % redis-cli      
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH myverysecretpassphrase
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "test"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

So all as expected. So tried the very simple python program:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='MYSERVERIP', port=6379, password='myverysecretpassphrase')

r.set('foo', 'bar')
value = r.get('foo')
print(value)
```

but get a long error trace:

```
(redis_test) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini redis_test % python test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bob/Documents/work/redis_test/test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    r.set('foo', 'bar')
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 2238, in set
    return self.execute_command("SET", *pieces, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1255, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1389, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in connect
    self.on_connect()
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 701, in on_connect
    auth_response = self.read_response()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 812, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 318, in read_response
    raw = self._buffer.readline()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 249, in readline
    self._read_from_socket()
  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 195, in _read_from_socket
    raise ConnectionError(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR)
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
```

Here is my environment:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/redis_test:
redis-py                  4.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
(redis_test) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini redis_test % python --version
Python 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to exclude typos, are you actually replacing `MYSERVERIP` with `127.0.0.1`? If not, that may be the cause of the issue - as the remote Redis server would be tunneled through `127.0.0.1:6379`, according to your spiped command line.

So that should read instead:

```py
r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, password='myverysecretpassphrase')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @efran, you correctly spotted my mistake. I got confused by the spiped syntax :) Take care all good now.